# Ionic 3 Push Notifications when app is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I’am developing an app in ionic. I’ve encountered a problem with push notifications. Which permissions I must ask to user to send him push notifications even when app is closed (like whatsapp)? And Which plugin I have to use to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to ask for permissions for that. Since you register your user app for using your notification service, the notification will be received, unless there's something in your android blocking the app to start on background (I had this kind of problem with ASUS Zenfone Zen UI, so I had to grant the permissions for app to start by itself... but the notification was sent, it was just blocked). OneSignal is a good and free service for doing that and it has a plugin for ionic:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/onesignal/.

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: Hi and thank you very much!!! I also have Asus Zenfone. So notification in other phone arrives normally or I have to implement a method to start app in background when notification arrives ?

Comment: @Bistaff it arrives normally. On Zenfone you can also give the app permission to start automatically (it's on a config for self-initializating). But don't worry, zenfone does that for most apps, including trustable ones, so it's not a problem with your app

Comment: Hi @Ronan Lopes, thanks for the answer!!! I have tried on my Asus and my app (ionic debug mode) was not accepted for self-initializing, so push notifications not arrive.. Do you know a way to bypass this configuration?

Comment: https://www.asus.com/support/FAQ/1013752/ this article shows how you can enable/disable that feature for your apps installed (even the ones who aren't signed from playstore), so after you allow your app, your notifications may arrive normally

Comment: @Bistaff you're welcome. If the answer was helpful to you, please consider upvote and mark it please =)